# How to deploy node js web server?

Tags: node.js, server

I am new to node. I created node server application using express and ran on local server localhost:3000. but i need to run on some address like 10.1.2.233, so it can be accessible on everywhere on internet. I read lot of documents about how to host node web server but i cant find any suitable solution. Please suggest.

Comment: What documents have you read? AWS, google app engine etc all are very easy to deploy to.

Comment: i saw many ways to deploy node js server like AWS and AZURE. but i want to create my own server and i have dedicated PC for that. so that i need some sort of tool to host my server on my machine and get some ip address. so i can access the node server any where in internet. but i dont know how to make my machine as web server.

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are using express when starting the server, you can do something like this:

```js
app.listen(3000, '0.0.0.0') // 127.0.0.1/localhost is the default;
```

Notice the `0.0.0.0`. This just opens the app to be accessed via remote machines.

Comment: I am able to run this in local server. I want to host my server like i need some ip address which can be accessible from any where in internet.

Comment: Oh okay, so for that you gotta have a web server of some kind. You can get a free one month trial on AWS. There are lots of resources on YouTube where you can learn how to deploy to AWS.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to make my pc as a web server? instead of AWS or AZURE.

Comment: Yes, for that you just need to make sure that you have Static IP. Once you made sure of that, then you can run your app port 80. So it is accessible by default when someone types in your IP.

Comment: Thanks Nadir, This is what i am looking for. if i get static IP then can i use my server with that static IP anywhere in internet?

Answer (score 0):

Where ever the app is hosted it would need a public ip and a port open to the node app.

Say your public ip is 192.168.0.1 and you hosted the express app at port 3000. You would access the app via the address and the port in the browser:

192.168.0.1:3000

If this is your local machine then you need to make sure your isp allows for the port to be open and then you need to open that port on the firewall of your router.

Feel free to ask more question! I've don't this through apache and nginx and issued ssl's to their hostnames.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that 192.168.0.1 is, in fact, a private IP address. See [here](https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters/). Otherwise, this answer is good.

Comment: It means i need to get a static IP from ISP. then i am able to access the IP and port from anywhere in internet.

Comment: I do my dev work on my home server, I don't go static because I don't expect people to route to that location and I can handle if my isp changes my IP.

Alternatively you could do application hosting with Heroku or AWS or if you like a whole VPS!

Comment: Keep in mind if your hosting from your house there are a few ports that ISP's like to block because they don't want people from home to access business class services. You probably wont have luck hosting through port 80 or 443.